# MongoDB $and query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want a query in MongoDB that does the following:

- A document returned `profession.organization` property can be the string 'bank'.
- A document returned `profession.city` property can be the string 'NY'.
- However, when the document has 'bank' for 'profession.organization' AND 'NY' for 'profession.city' the document must be excluded.

To sum up a document can have city 'NY' or organization 'bank' but must be excluded if it has these properties at the same time.

What I have tried so far.

```
    targetObj = await db.db(MDBC.db).collection(MDBC.pC)
        .aggregate([{
            $match: {
                $and: [
                { 'profession.organization': { $ne: 'bank' } }, 
                { 'profession.city': { $ne: 'NY' } }
              ]
            }
        }, { $sample: { size: 1 } }]).next();
```

Comment: So right now it's not working? What documents are you getting in the end?

Comment: No it's not working. I'm getting neither organization 'bank', nor city 'NY'

Comment: So, in the end, every document must have `profession.organization` as `bank`?

Comment: Edited my answer, should be a bit more clear now

Comment: So you want a sample document from all documents such that each document doesn't have those two properties. See my answer.

Comment: `$elemMatch` could work if you had `profession` field as array [with $elemMatch](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gpMcZyzWIU-)

Comment: @Valijon I updated my answer

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen Check my answer if you also want to include docs that don't have either of those two properties or if you want to shorten the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
targetObj = await db.db(MDBC.db).collection(MDBC.pC)
 .aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            { "profession.organization": "bank" },
            { "profession.city": "NY" }
          ]
        },
        {
          $or: [
            {
              "profession.organization": "bank",
              "profession.city": { $ne: "NY" }
            },
            {
              "profession.organization": { $ne: "bank" },
              "profession.city": "NY"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $sample: {size: 1} } ]).next();
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yf3dbNn6pIi)

Answer (score 0):

I think the query which is used in the accepted answer could be much shorter.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "profession.organization": "bank",
          "profession.city": {
            $ne: "NY"
          }
        },
        {
          "profession.organization": {
            $ne: "bank"
          },
          "profession.city": "NY"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sample: {
      size: 1
    }
  }
])
```

and one more thing I want to say is if you also want to include documents that don't have either of those two properties then you should use this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "profession.organization": "bank",
          "profession.city": {
            $ne: "NY"
          }
        },
        {
          "profession.organization": {
            $ne: "bank"
          },
          "profession.city": "NY"
        },
        {
          "profession.organization": {
            $ne: "bank"
          },
          "profession.city": {
            $ne: "NY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sample: {
      size: 1
    }
  }
])
```

this will also include documents like-

```
  {
    "profession": {
      "organization": "someBank",
      "city": "notNA"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I get this errmsg: 'unknown top level operator: $elemMatch',

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, there is no matching operator in MongoDB to help out with this. But you can achieve a similar result by combining the `$or` and `$ne` operators. Try something like this for your query:

```js
const query = {
  $or: [
    {
      // Include all non-banks outside of NY.
      'profession.city': { $ne: 'NY' },
      'profession.organization': { $ne: 'bank' }
    },
    {
      // Include all non-banks in NY.
      'profession.city': 'NY',
      'profession.organization': { $ne: 'bank' }
    },
    {
      // Include all banks outside of NY.
      'profession.city': { $ne: 'NY' },
      'profession.organization': 'bank'
    }
  ]
};
```